# How to generate faster sliding-window features in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set like:

```
 Region  Product  Date        Order
 North   A        1/1/2019    10 
 North   A        1/2/2019    11
 ....
 North   A        1/29/2019   1
 North   A        1/30/2019   150
```

I am creating lag features (previous-date order) by using loops:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()

for k in df['Region'].unique():
    temp_df2 = df[df['Region']==k]
    for j in temp_df2['Product'].unique():
         temp_df3 = temp_df2[temp_df2['Product']==j]
         for i in range(28,56):
             temp_df3['lag_{}'.format(-i)] = temp_df3['Order'].shift(i).fillna(0)
             temp_df = temp_df.append(temp_df3)
```

The time to run this nested loop is very long. How can I preprocess the data faster?
Thanks in advance!

Expected output:

```
 Region  Product  Date        Order    Lag_28   Lag_29
 North   A        1/1/2019    10       N/A      N/A
 ....
 North   A        1/30/2019   150      11       10
```

Comment: Edited my post. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` would be a bit faster (and cleaner):

```
groups = df.groupby(['Region', 'Product'])['Order']

for i in range(28,56):
    df[f'Lag_{i}'] = groups.shift(i)
```